# How to create canvas which size matches user's screen?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How to do it without borders?
I try it like that.

CSS: `body {margin: 0;}`

JS:

```
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

But screen has white lines on top and left sides. Also it has both scroll bars.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It would solve your issue.

```
body {    
    margin: 0 !important;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: !important is not needed. In fact it's better avoid using it.

Comment: `overflow: hidden` helps to avoid scroll bars. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @levshkatov: Both the things helped still u accepted another answer. :D

Comment: Oh, both answers helps me. But I can't select them both.

Comment: Its okay. @levshkatov. u can select any of them which ever is best suiting to you. I normally look on the smallest and easiest one to choose the accepted answer

Comment: @MohitShrivastava I have another problem. My width resolution is 1920px but window.innerWidth returns 1280px. Why and can you help me?

Comment: You can post another question with the code ... I think that would be easier for me to understand what you are asking. If I try to assume will be a problem for both. Hope you wont mind asking. Please also provide the link of new question. I would love to solve it

Comment: @MohitShrivastava I can only post once every 90 minutes. Thus I tried to ask it here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

CSS :

```
body{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

JS :

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('#myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;

ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fta462c2/1/

Comment: JS code I have the same. Thanks for `overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the width is the width of the whole screen. This makes it as wide as the window, but since it is move partially over due to padding/margins, you need to either fix the padding/margins, or change the width and height as follow:

```
canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 20;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 20;
```